# Excel - Copy & paste cells within range when date falls between two user set parameters

Tags: vba, excel

I am desperate to make this macro work.  I would like a button click to prompt users to enter a beginning and end date, then the macro to copy cells data from B:F in every row where cell A* contains a date within the range starting with row 4.  It would then focus to the destination sheet and paste the info into columns H:L starting at row 7.

The source table looks something like this, where rows 1-3 are devoted to sheet info and should be exempt from the macro's analysis

```
   |   A  |  B  |  C  |  D  |  E  |  F  |
-----------------------------------------
4  | Date |INFO |INFO |INFO |INFO |INFO |
5  | Date |INFO |INFO |INFO |INFO |INFO |
6  | Date |INFO |INFO |INFO |INFO |INFO |
7  | Date |INFO |INFO |INFO |INFO |INFO |
```

The destination sheet looks like this, with rows 1-6 being used for sheet info.

```
   |  H  |  I  |  J  |  K  |  L  |
----------------------------------
7  |INFO |INFO |INFO |INFO |INFO | 
8  |INFO |INFO |INFO |INFO |INFO |
9  |INFO |INFO |INFO |INFO |INFO |
10 |INFO |INFO |INFO |INFO |INFO |
```

And the code I have tried to piecemeal together is

```
Sub Copy_Click()

Dim r As Range
Set r = Range("B:F")

startdate = CDate(InputBox("Begining Date"))
enddate = CDate(InputBox("End Date"))

For Each Cell In Sheets("SOURCE").Range("A:A")
    If Cell.Value >= startdate And Cell.Value <= enddate Then
        Sheets("SOURCE").Select
        r.Select
        Selection.Copy

        Sheets("DESTINATION").Select
        ActiveSheet.Range("H:L").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Sheets("SOURCE").Select
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

This is obviously not working, and there are no instructions to have it paste to the next available row, nor start on row 7 when pasting to the destination sheet.

Any help would be amazing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested:

```
Sub Copy_Click()

    Dim startdate As Date, enddate As Date
    Dim rng As Range, destRow As Long
    Dim shtSrc As Worksheet, shtDest As Worksheet
    Dim c As Range

    Set shtSrc = Sheets("SOURCE")
    Set shtDest = Sheets("DESTINATION")

    destRow = 7 'start copying to this row

    startdate = CDate(InputBox("Begining Date"))
    enddate = CDate(InputBox("End Date"))

    'don't scan the entire column...
    Set rng = Application.Intersect(shtSrc.Range("A:A"), shtSrc.UsedRange)

    For Each c In rng.Cells
        If c.Value >= startdate And c.Value <= enddate Then
            'Starting one cell to the right of c,
            '  copy a 5-cell wide block to the other sheet,
            '  pasting it in Col H on row destRow
            c.Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, 5).Copy _
                          shtDest.Cells(destRow, 8)

            destRow = destRow + 1

        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: @TimWilliams Can you please explain how this script works? Because I have the same problem, and I just can't get how this works. Thanks!

Comment: @ramedju - Which part are you having a problem with?

Comment: Starting with the for each loop, I get confused with the numbers.

Comment: See my comment explaining the copy part