# Need to copy full rows int new sheet based on date range

Tags: vba, excel

Have tried searching for the answer I need but they just fall short (I think).

I have an excel table with 17 columns. One of the columns is a date column and I need a separate sheet where it pulls the entire rows that meet a date range criteria - a fortnightly date range which can be chosen based on a dropdown list of specific fortnightly end dates

I have tried changing the dates into numbers but to no avail. Below is a simplified version of the headings and it is the date held column that I need to sort into fortnightly entries onto a new sheet.

```
Select End Date 07/02/2017
```

Surname    Forename     DOB    Age  M/F    Date Held

I have tried Index match and vlookup but cannot seem to get it to work. I'm a total novice as to VBA and have tried amending some answers to my need but to no avail.

Probably the problem isn't clearly explained so here goes again: I have a sheet where all of the data is stored and need to send fortnightly reports for those incidents fell between a specified fortnight. Is it possible to do this using something that pulls data from the master sheet to a new sheet, depending on the fortnight you select from the dropdown. For example 25/01/2017 - 07/02/2017?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Tristan

Comment: What did you not understand about the other answers?  What have you tried?

Comment: did you try this for example?  What "fell short" about the answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24875320/excel-copy-paste-cells-within-range-when-date-falls-between-two-user-set-par

Answer (score 0):

You should make another column in your original data. In it, you should put fortnight labels in each row, e.g. for all dates from 1.1.2017 to 14.1.2017 the column Fortnight should have a value of 1.1.2017. Next fortnight label would be 15.1.2017 and so on.

Then on the new sheet you simply make a pivot table, with the original table as the source, and display the rows using the Fortnight column as a filter.